# Power Bi DAX: Cumulative Sum not Showing Correct Data

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am having trouble making a cumulative sum.

It is showing data from the previous column instead of being a cumulative.

I have tested it out on a test file and it works fine but using the same format of the formula:

QuoteValue running total in ClosedDate =

```
Sales running total in Date = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Sheet1'[Sales]),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED('Sheet1'[Date]),
        ISONORAFTER('Sheet1'[Date], MAX('Sheet1'[Date]), DESC)
    )
)
```

Im not sure what i am doing wrong, ive used `ALLSELECTED, FILTER(ALL, ALL`

The Quotevalue and Date are both in the same table and all other fields im using in the visual are all in the same table.

Im stumped.

Here is a dummy sheet i have put together.

[Dummy Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6J8Xo.png)

Comment: https://www.daxpatterns.com/cumulative-total/

Answer (score 0):

```
Sales running total in Date = 
var person = 'Sheet1'[Person]
var toDate = 'Sheet1'[Date]
return CALCULATE(
    SUM('Sheet1'[Sales]),
        FILTER('Sheet1', 'Sheet1'[Person] = Person && 'Sheet1'[Date] <= toDate)
)
```

What we do here is that for each row, we get the other rows where persons are same and date is lower or equal. From this we calculate the sum.